# .sort is not a function on an array

Tags: javascript, chess

Steps to reproduce:
1: Visit https://www.chess.com/play/computer
2: Paste JS code in the console

Expected results:
Pieces are printed by their square number ascendingly

Actual results:
`Uncaught TypeError: newPieces.sort is not a function` error is thrown

JS code:

```js
pieces = ["r","n","b","q","k","p"];
colors = ["w","b"];
squareTemplate = "square-";
boardTemplate = "chess-board.layout-board";

function updatePieces(){
    return document.querySelectorAll("chess-board.layout-board .piece");
}

function getFen(isFlipped){
    
}

function evalMove(){

}

console.log("Starting up ...");
const board = document.querySelector(boardTemplate);

let newPieces = [];
newPieces = updatePieces();

newPieces.sort(function(a,b){return a.classList[2].split('-')[1] - b.classList[2].split('-')[1]});

let fenRows = [];

for(i=0;i<newPieces.length;i++){
    let classList = newPieces[i].classList;
    let pieceColor = classList[1][0];
    let pieceType = classList[1][1];
    let pieceSquare = classList[2].split('-')[1];

    //console.log(" Piece color is: " + pieceColor + " it is: " + pieceType + " and it is in: " + pieceSquare);
    if(pieceColor == 'w'){
        pieceType.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        pieceType.toLowerCase();
    }

    fen
}
```

So, basically JS is trying to tell me that is not an array, well, if it is not an array, then I am born in Bangladesh, because it is `let newPieces = [];`

Comment: Your updatePieces function does not return an array. It returns a NodeList. I recommend you switch to TypeScript.

Comment: Asking someone to switch to TS when the solution is just `Array.from(nodelist)` is a really weird.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sort()` is a method located on the `Array.prototype` which is what you want to use where as `querySelectorAll()` returns a static NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors not an array. this is why your getting your exception. if you wish to use sort, you need to convert it into an array.

You can convert it to an array using `array.from`

```
const pieces = document.querySelectorAll("chess-board.layout-board .piece");
const arr = Array.from(pieces);
```

Comment: ... for example by `return [...document.querySelectorAll()];`.

Comment: With this method, it does return only one element, so now effectively it is `document.querySelector`. Way with Array.from works

Answer (score 0):

`updatePieces` function in not returning an `array`, and `sort` method only work on array's, please first check `updatePieces()` function output

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to propose a way to fix it ?